# Javascript not properly called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been stumped on this for upwards of six steady hours.

My end goal is an interactive Tic-Tac-Toe web game, but I'm trying to test out the JavaScript by using a simple JQuery fadeout function that'll get rid of the first panel once the user clicks it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Clicky.js" type="text/javascript src="Clicky.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <h1>
        <table>

        <!-- This is a table of independently defined background panels arranged in a 3x3 table -->
            <tr><td><div id = "panel1" class="backgroundPanel">&nbsp;</div></td><td><div id = "panel2" class="backgroundPanel">&nbsp;</div></td><td><div id = "panel3" class="backgroundPanel">&nbsp;</div></td></tr>
            <tr><td><div id = "panel4" class="backgroundPanel">&nbsp;</div></td><td><div id = "panel5" class="backgroundPanel">&nbsp;</div></td><td><div id = "panel6" class="backgroundPanel">&nbsp;</div></td></tr>
            <tr><td><div id = "panel7" class="backgroundPanel">&nbsp;</div></td><td><div id = "panel8" class="backgroundPanel">&nbsp;</div></td><td><div id = "panel9" class="backgroundPanel">&nbsp;</div></td></tr>

        </table>

    </h1>


</body>


</html>
```

This is the html code.  The table helps arrange the different panels in a 3x3 grid, and the other panels are just placeholders for now until I know the JavaScript is working.  The only one of consequence is panel1.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#panel1").click(function () {
        $(this).fadeout();
    });
});
```

This is all the JavaScript code I implemented.

I've been making slight revisions based on multiple sources, but the JavaScript still isn't working.  It shows up under scripts when I use Chrome's f12 overlay, but nothing is executed.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks funky, you are including the source for the js file twice, and you are missing a quote which is probably eating up the rest of the page.

```
 <script src="Clicky.js" type="text/javascript src="Clicky.js">  </script>
```

try

```
 <script src="Clicky.js"></script>
```

you can confirm that it is being imported correctly by adding a

```
console.log("test")
```

in your js file and checking the developer console.

Comment: [There is no need to use the `type` attribute on `script` tags](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Y2Y0U-2qJMs#t=936s).

Comment: I thought it'd be a dumb oversight on my part... thanks a bunch for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your browser's console you should see an error message that says something along the lines of:

> TypeError: $(...).fadeout is not a function

JavaScript is case-sensitive, the jQuery method you were trying to use is named [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) (upper-case `O`), not `fadeout`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the script is working and I'm editing without problems now!